# Create Tensorflow Dataset with dataframe of images and labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, computer-vision, tensorflow-datasets

I want to create a dataset with tensorflow and feed this with images as array (dtype=unit8) and labels as string. The images and the according labels are stored in a dataframe and the columns named as `Image as Array` and  `Labels`.

| Image as Array (type = array) | Labels (type = string) |
| --- | --- |
| img_1 | 'ok' |
| img_2 | 'not ok' |
| img_3 | 'ok' |
| img_4 | 'ok' |

My challenge: I don't know how to feed the Dataset out of a dataframe, the most tutorials prefer the way to load the data from a directory.

Thank you in forward and I hope you can help me to load the images in the dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually pass a dataframe directly to `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(data={'images': [np.random.random((64, 64, 3)) for _ in range(100)],
                        'labels': ['ok', 'not ok']*50})

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((list(df['images'].values), df['labels'].values)).batch(2)

for x, y in dataset.take(1):
  print(x.shape, y)
# (2, 64, 64, 3) tf.Tensor([b'ok' b'not ok'], shape=(2,), dtype=string)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the shape of image arrays is 70,162. So I think my output ```(70, 162) tf.Tensor(b'IO-Image', shape=(), dtype=string)``` looks good.  What does the 'b' mean by ```tf.Tensor(b...``` ?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal#:~:text=The%20b%20denotes%20a%20byte,Bytes%20are%20the%20actual%20data.

Comment: Yes I unterstand, the string will convert into bytes. In your output is a list of your labels. In my output is only one of two labels. If check the dataframe with the unique-method there are two labels. What is the reason?

Comment: two labels because I am using a batch size of 2..

Comment: Ahh, yes. I do a mistake. I forgot the ```.batch(2)```.  Now, I get the same output. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

One of possibility is to use `range` to create index dataset and then map array and label together.

```
# array
img = np.random.rand(4, 2, 2, 2)
label = np.array(['ok', 'not ok', 'ok', 'ok'])

# convert to tf constant
img = tf.constant(img)
label = tf.constant(label)

# create dataset with 0 - 3 index
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(len(label))
# map dataset
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: (img[x, :, :, :], label[x]))
```

output:

```
<MapDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(2, 2, 2), dtype=tf.float64, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name=None))>
```

output list- second idx:

```
for i in dataset:
    print(list(i)[1])

tf.Tensor(b'ok', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'not ok', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'ok', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'ok', shape=(), dtype=string)
```